# Where do I place the code to disable the mobile responsive in the Wordpress theme Ocean?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to disable the mobile formatting in the WP theme Ocean and I have this snip of code that should work.  I know it needs to go in the Theme Functions (functions.php) file but I don't know where to place it within that file.  I've tried at the end inside of the final braces, the code compiles but doesn't change anything.

```
    //disable mobile responsive
            function no_meta_viewport() {
                return false;
            }
            add_filter( 'ocean_meta_viewport', 'no_meta_viewport' );
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ocean themes using widths as percent that mean even if change viewerport still it will act like mobil also the theme not using bootstrap that why you cant do with css.Shortly i dont think solution be easy, it need a lot of edit.